# How can I track down what's slowing down Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm running a large C++ solution, and it's incredibly slow. By "slow", I mean that the output window is spitting out logs line...by...line... and if I hit an assert it can take almost a minute for the debugger to catch up and show my execution point. (The exe halts right away, but VS is still printing in the output window for *ages*).

The exe is running fine; not that slow at all. But the debugger is way behind.

I've deleted all breakpoints, closed all other windows (threads, watch, etc...), disabled intellisence, added a symbol cache, removed the symbol cache, and probably some other stuff. Google isn't any help (searching for "slow visual studio" and various other things turns up a lot, but nothing that helps).

A couple of coworkers are having the same problem, and we're stumped. Does anyone have any ideas for tracking down the bottleneck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that an extension wasn't behaving very nicely. This was the one thing that I hadn't tried, so I disabled all extensions and the problem went away. Then I did a binary search with the extensions and eventually narrowed down the culprit. Haven't had a problem since!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `/log` switch

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/11/27/did-you-know-there-s-a-way-to-have-visual-studio-log-its-activity-for-troubleshooting-366.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/24/troubleshooting-with-the-activity-log.aspx

Also, make sure that your symbol environment variable is not pointing to unreachable Url, Are machines connected to internet ?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mahuja/archive/2008/07/08/resolving-very-slow-symbol-loading-with-vs-2008-during-debugging.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but neither helped find the problem in the end. Although I did learn something. :)